# restore a physical volume that I removed with vgreduce --removemissing

Tags: filesystems, lvm

As a disaster recovery exercise I pulled the plug on one of the drives (/dev/sda) that was part of my mirrored logical volume.
I was able to make the system bootable by

```
vgreduce --removemissing --force kubuntu-vg
```

lvs reports

```
  WARNING: ignoring metadata seqno 118 on /dev/sda5 for seqno 120 on /dev/sdb1 for VG kubuntu-vg.
  WARNING: Inconsistent metadata found for VG kubuntu-vg
  WARNING: outdated PV /dev/sda5 seqno 118 has been removed in current VG kubuntu-vg seqno 120.
  LV      VG         Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home_lv kubuntu-vg rwi-aor-r- <1.76t                                    100.00
```

But now I want to undo that - so I plug the drive back in and now I need to get that drive back on the system as a physical volume

What the physical volumes used to look like

```
pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---


PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               kubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476809
  Free PE               16008
  Allocated PE          460801
  PV UUID               X5FdPD-xkae-gXSe-wSbH-ngl7-SiPD-EjeYP6
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               kubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476810
  Free PE               16009
  Allocated PE          460801
  PV UUID               6XNs0p-k0f3-1Zru-txVO-0AWy-IfWo-4YhGvD
```

What pvdisplay shows now - only one physical volume

```
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               kubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476810
  Free PE               16009
  Allocated PE          460801
  PV UUID               6XNs0p-k0f3-1Zru-txVO-0AWy-IfWo-4YhGvD
```

From this golinuxcloud document
[5 easy steps to recover LVM2 partition, PV, VG, LVM metdata in Linux](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/recover-lvm2-partition-restore-vg-pv-metadata/)
I think the command I want to run is pvcreate  with the --restorefile option.
The golinuxcloud recomends running this in test mode first

```
pvcreate --test --uuid "X5FdPD-xkae-gXSe-wSbH-ngl7-SiPD-EjeYP6" --restorefile  /etc/lvm/archive/kubuntu-vg_00002-168403895.vg /dev/sda




 TEST MODE: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be (de)activated.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid X5FdPD-xkae-gXSe-wSbH-ngl7-SiPD-EjeYP6.
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 6XNs0p-k0f3-1Zru-txVO-0AWy-IfWo-4YhGvD.

  WARNING: ignoring metadata seqno 118 on /dev/sda5 for seqno 120 on /dev/sdb1 for VG kubuntu-vg.
  WARNING: Inconsistent metadata found for VG kubuntu-vg
  WARNING: outdated PV /dev/sda5 seqno 118 has been removed in current VG kubuntu-vg seqno 120.
  Device /dev/sda excluded by a filter.
```

It seems to me that what is foiling sucess here is this "Device /dev/sda excluded by a filter". What do you do about this?

The backup file referenced in my command is described by `vgcfgrestore --list kubuntu-vg` thusly

```
 File:         /etc/lvm/archive/kubuntu-vg_00002-168403895.vg
  VG name:      kubuntu-vg
  Description:  Created *before* executing 'vgreduce --removemissing --force kubuntu-vg'
  Backup Time:  Sun Jan  8 13:34:23 2023
```